# TypeError with Vitest: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, typeerror, vite, vitest

I am trying to set up testing for my React app using Vitest, but I am experiencing an error which must be due to some missing dependency or error in my test suite. I'm unsure what exactly is the cause. When I try to run my tests I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
```

It says it's happening in my Login component, which contains a hook from `react-hook-form`.

```
export default function Login() {

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
                                       ^
```

When I remove this apparently problematic line it causes a similar problem elsewhere, where it says that an instance of `useReducer` is `null`.

This is what my setupTests.js looks like:

```
import { server } from './mocks/server';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());
```

Here is my Vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        setupFiles: './src/setupTests.js',
    }
})
```

And here is my package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "my-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "knex": "knex",
    "test": "vitest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cloudinary": "^1.30.0",
    "connect-session-knex": "^3.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "knex": "^2.0.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "passport": "^0.5.3",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "vitest": "^0.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "jsdom": "^20.0.0",
    "msw": "^0.42.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
}
```

All these hooks work perfectly fine outside of the tests, so I am not sure why they are undefined.

I tried installing `@testing-library/react-hooks` in the hope that it might fix my problem but I was unable to do so as it doesn't appear to support React 18.

I'd really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem so I investigated a bit and I figured out a working solution.

## Working solution with `@testing-library/react` > 13.1

Use `renderHook` method from `@testing-library/react` package and wrap your hooks with it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, renderHook, screen } from '@testing-library/react'; 
import { describe, test } from 'vitest';
import { FormProvider, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

describe('Input', () => {
  test('should render an Input component', () => {
    type FormValues = {
      field: string;
    };

    const { result } = renderHook(
      () => useForm<FormValues>({
        defaultValues: {
          field: '',
        },
      })
    );
    const methods = result.current;
    const { register } = methods;

    render(
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form>
          <input {...register('field')} data-testid="my-field" />
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    );

    expect(screen.getByTestId('my-field').toHaveAttribute('name', 'field'));
  });
});
```

## In details

First of all, the reason why the hooks are not working is because we are in a testing context so the functions we are using need to be mocked.
`@testing-library` provides a solution to being able to use the hooks. Since `@testing-library/react@^13.1`, the package `@testing-library/react-hooks` is useless as you can read here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-hooks#user-content-a-note-about-react-18-support

Let's say that we have a test like this using React Hook Form and Vitest:

```
import React from 'react';
import { describe, test } from 'vitest';
import { FormProvider, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

describe('Input', () => {
  test('should render an Input component', () => {
    type FormValues = {
      field: string;
    };

    const methods = useForm<FormValues>({ defaultValues: { field: '' } }); 
    const { register } = methods;

    render(
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form>
          <input {...register('field')} data-testid="my-field" />
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    );

    expect(screen.getByTestId('my-field').toHaveAttribute('name', 'field'));
  });
});
```

This test will crash with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
```

To make it work, add this import:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
```

And replace the previous `useForm` React Hook Form hook by:

```
const { result } = renderHook(
  () => useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      field: ''
    },
  })
);
const methods = result.current;
```

And now the test is working well

## Before `@testing-library/react@^13.1`

Run the following command to add `@testing-library/react-hooks` to your project:

```
npm i --save-dev @testing-library/react-hooks
```

And import `renderHook` from the package you just installed

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks`
```

The documentation can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-hooks#table-of-contents